# Update ONE Custom Field based on Several other custom fields?

Tags: custom-field

I have a custom object that I would like to update based on several other custom object variables.  Can someone help me get started on this?  I want ONE FIELD (*booked_revenue_by_Quarter* **IE: Q1-2014=$XXXXX**) to have a Currency field with ALL ammounts of additional purchases summed up.

EXAMPLE:  **BOOKED_REVENUE_Quarter_C Field needs to be updated when**

1. Add'l purchase of *A_object_c* (checkbox) is marked 
   OR
2. Add'l purchase of *B_object_c* (checkbox) is marked 
   OR
3. Add'l Purchase of *C_object_c* (checkbox) is marked.

**IN addition to**

1. Add'l purchase date_c of *D_object_c* (date field) is either Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4
   **OR**
2. Add'l purchase date_c of *E_object_c* (date field) is either Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4 
   **OR**
3. Add'l purchase date_c of *F_object_c* (date field) is either Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4

**ON TOP OF**

1. Add'l purchase ammount_c of *G_object_c* (date field) is $XXXXXX
   **OR**
2. Add'l purchase ammount_c of *H_object_c* (date field) is $XXXXXX 
   **OR**
3. Add'l purchase ammount_c of *I_object_c* (date field) is $XXXXXX

Comment: Are there relations between these objects and records ? This looks like a combination of triggers, but that may depend on your overall use case and datamodel. As this is quite a broad question, trying to specify it to the generic essential question would improve the likelyhood of a solution being answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this for a trigger of a field update? I'm going to assume field update, but the same logic would apply for trigger, just with different syntax. For the Q1-Q4 part, it seems like you're trying to say if the date is this year? How does this look?

```
AND(
    OR(
        A_object_c,
        B_object_c,
        C_object_c
    ),
    OR
    (
        YEAR(D_object_c) == YEAR( TODAY() ),
        YEAR(E_object_c) == YEAR( TODAY() ),
        YEAR(F_object_c) == YEAR( TODAY() )
    )
)
```

Comment: I've updated my original post to help with the specifics.